# ExtJs Store.save()?

Tags: extjs, commit

How do I handle the `save()` method of the data store on the back end.(my C# code)?
Do I need any extra config settings for the store to enable the `save()` method?
If anyone could just point me in the right direction that would be great?

```
    var writer = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
    encode: true
});

// create the Data Store
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    root: 'Data.items',
    idProperty: 'Empid',
    writer: writer,
    fields: ['Empid', 'Firstname', 'Surname', 'Username'],
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: AppRootPath + 'EmployeeDetails/GetSAASUsers',
        method: 'POST'
    })//proxy
});//new Ext.data.JsonStore
```

Hod do i configure my stiore to support a save method which will update the records in the database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Ext.data.Store.commitChanges()` is a client-side-only method. It does not communicate with the server in any form. The method is used to reset the modification status of the store's records and persist their changes (on the client-side only).

`Ext.data.Store.save()` is the method that actually uses the configured connection to talk to your server-side application. To be able to provide more information you'd need to post some code snippets.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the question and added some code. How do I handle the save method on the server side? Do I need to specify something else in the store config for this?

Comment: @Shane87. For the C# side. Are you using WCF services? MVC?

Comment: @Shane87: Unfortunately I am more familiar with WCF and EXT JS. Could you post some code snippets you have from the server side? Like the EmployeeDetails Controller?

Comment: @Shane87: Guessing MVC3? [link] (http://myxaab.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/extjs-and-asp-net-mvc-3-crud-datagrid/)

Comment: Note that Ext.data.Store.save() has been deprecated in ExtJS 4.x; one must use [Ext.data.Store.sync()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Config option [autoSync](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-autoSync) is available for stores since ExtJS 4.

Answer (score -2):

I am not familiar with C#, but I would imagine you would need to send your stores data as a JSON Object to your C# cost with some kind of Ajax request