# Saving a Tree panel after changing node order

Tags: extjs6-classic

ExtJS 6.0.2:

I need to send to my server any changes in the index order of my Tree Panel.

After reading this: [Ext 4.2 Using proxy to save tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080718/ext-4-2-using-proxy-to-save-tree) and this [ExtJs Store.save()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297952/extjs-store-save) and [How to save JSON file when use it as ExtJs grid store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381708/how-to-save-json-file-when-use-it-as-extjs-grid-store) and some confusing Sencha docs...

1) I need to configure a writer in my Store's Proxy. Result: Nothing.

2) I need to set `autoSync:true` in my Store. Result: Nothing.

3) I need to set the `fields` property. Result: Nothing.

4) I need to put the `index` attribute into `fields` property. Result: My server detected a call, but nothing came with the request parameter list.

5) Need to put the `rootProperty:'data'` attribute in the `writer`. Result: Wow! My server detected a JSON string with the 2 nodes I swap.

```
data = [{"index":5,"id":"6"},{"index":4,"id":"12"}]
```

All good, but I've noticed a collateral effect: The two swapped nodes was replaced by the two parent nodes and very weird things start to happen...

What I'm doing wrong?

Before:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxfU4.png]

After try to swap `Parking` and `Continentes`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEs72.png]

My Store:

```
var layerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoSync:true,
    fields: [

                { name: 'index', type: 'int' },
                { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'serviceUrl', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'layerName', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'originalServiceUrl', type: 'string' }
             ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'getLayersTreeNode',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },        
        writer: {
            type:'json',
            allowSingle:false,
            encode:true,
            rootProperty:'data'
        }        
    },

    root: {
        text: 'Camadas',
        id: 0,
        index:0,
        expanded: true
    },
    listeners : {
        write: function(store, operation, opts){
            alert("Fired!");
        }
    }

});
```

My Tree:

```
var layerTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: layerStore,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
        }
    },
    scrollable: true,
    scroll: 'both',
    height: 350,
    width: 300,
    flex:1,
    useArrows: true,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text: 'Expandir',
            handler : layerTreeExpandir
        }, {
            text: 'Recolher',
            handler : layerTreeRecolher
        }]
    }],
    listeners: {
        itemclick: layerTreeItemClick,
        checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts){

            node.eachChild(function(n) {
                node.cascadeBy(function(n){
                    n.set('checked', checked);
                });
            });


            //check parent node if child node is check
            p = node.parentNode;
            var pChildCheckedCount = 0;
            p.suspendEvents();
            p.eachChild(function(c) { 
                if (c.get('checked')) pChildCheckedCount++; 
                    p.parentNode.set('checked', !!pChildCheckedCount);
                    p.set('checked', !!pChildCheckedCount);
                });
            p.resumeEvents();
        }    

    }
});
```

A JSON Tree response:

```
[{"checked":false,"cls":"","id":"1","idNodeParent":27,"index":0,"layerName":"osm:highway-label","leaf":true,"originalServiceUrl":"","serviceUrl":"http://192.168.25.25:8080/geoserver/osm/wms","text":"Nomes das Vias"},{"checked":false,"cls":"","id":"2","idNodeParent":27,"index":1,"layerName":"osm:vias","leaf":true,"originalServiceUrl":"","serviceUrl":"http://192.168.25.25:8080/geoserver/osm/wms","text":"Vias"},{"checked":false,"cls":"","id":"3","idNodeParent":27,"index":2,"layerName":"osm:placenames-medium","leaf":true,"originalServiceUrl":"","serviceUrl":"http://192.168.25.25:8080/geoserver/osm/wms","text":"Nomes de Localidades"},{"checked":false,"cls":"","id":"4","idNodeParent":27,"index":3,"layerName":"osm:parking-area","leaf":true,"originalServiceUrl":"","serviceUrl":"http://192.168.25.25:8080/geoserver/osm/wms","text":"Parking"},{"checked":false,"cls":"","id":"5","idNodeParent":27,"index":4,"layerName":"land","leaf":true,"originalServiceUrl":"","serviceUrl":"http://192.168.25.25:8080/geoserver/osm/wms","text":"Continentes"},{"checked":false,"cls":"","id":"24","idNodeParent":27,"index":5,"layerName":"osm:powergenerator","leaf":true,"originalServiceUrl":"","serviceUrl":"http://192.168.25.25:8080/geoserver/osm/wms?","text":"Geradores"}]
```

Comment: I found out that the name changing is because I'm sending back a root JSON nodes. I did not know that I must send a response to EVERY request. A little help from here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?107217-JSON-Response-Format-for-HTTPProxy-on-create-update

Comment: Now I must discover how to know the kind of operation the client is doing to send back the proper response.

Answer (score 0):

After some research here: http://alvinalexander.com/source-code/software-dev/sencha-store-ajax-json-proxy-readerwriter-example and here [how to get Extjs 4 store's request data on beforeload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492689/how-to-get-extjs-4-stores-request-data-on-beforeload-event) I've changed my Store:

Added global var: `ope`

Added to Proxy: `extraParams : { 'operation': ope }`

Added a listener:

```
listeners : {
    write: function(store, operation, opts){
        ope = operation.action;
        alert(ope);
    }
}
```

I can see the operation is `update` but seems the `ope` var is not taking the action value before send because its null (empty) at server side.

Find a way: removed `url` and added `api` to the proxy:

```
    api: {
        read: 'getLayersTreeNode',
        create: 'createLayersTreeNode',
        update: 'updateLayersTreeNode',
        destroy: 'destroyLayersTreeNode'
    }
```

for each operation I have a different action to handle at server side. Will send back an empty JSON to avoid mess the tree.